# Updating property values dynamically is replacing the entire object

Tags: typescript, object, parameters

I'm trying to update a dataStore service I'm building and I'm hung up on the strangest problem.

```
public setOptions(params: Params): void {

    console.log(this._dataStore.options); // always empty here!!!

    for (const key of Object.keys(params)) {
        this._dataStore['options'][key] = params[key];
    }

    console.log(this._dataStore.options); // parameter(s) added
}
```

Calling `setOptions()` with the initial set of URL parameters works and `_dataStore.options` contain the properties reflecting the incoming parameters.

**The problem is** anytime I call setOptions the options properties are replaced by the new `params` instead of updating them or adding new additions.

```
console.log(this._dataStore.options); // city: la
```

This makes no sense to me, can someone help me understand and how to properly update the .options object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen. Can you explain further with some examples of `_dataStore.options` both before and after calling `setOptions()` multiple times?

Comment: Are you trying to merge them  with existing perhaps? Issue is not clear at all

Comment: Yes I am trying to merge them. I explain in the code `properties are being replaced, not updated or added`

Comment: Can you please show examples of what you expect to happen given specific `params`

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in the code shown that would remove the `claimed` and `location` properties from `_dataStore.options`

Comment: Sure, page loads: `setOptions` is called and the url params are added as expected. Then the user changes their city and only that parameter exists on `_dataStore.options`. The city prop should be updated but the entire object is replaced. That more clear?

Answer (score 1):

Merge them with `Object.assign()`

```
for (const key of Object.keys(params)) {
    Object.assign(this._dataStore['options'][key] , params[key]);
   // or reverse arguments if applicable 
}
```

Comment: Hey Chalietfl this is where I began only I thought `Object.assign` was meant to combine properties into a new object? Also it's giving me an error `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: Target can be a  new object or if it is existing one it copies properties and values from source(s)

Comment: If you have that error likely that dataStore doesn't have that key and need to create an object in that instance. If you would just provide some sample data in order to run this it would help. Hard for us to know how either object is constructed

Comment: Hmm dataStore is instantiated like this: `private _dataStore = {
    options: {},
    results: []
};`

Comment: Ok then it would seem you need to check if keys exist first

Comment: Ok, I thought assignment was fine to do this way even if they dont exist. Wait isnt that the point of Object.assign?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184114/discussion-between-tr3b-and-charlietfl).

Comment: Logic is simple...update existing with `Object.assign()`. If not existing use code in question